# How can I specify html_theme_path to sphinx-build with -D arguments?

Tags: python-sphinx

I am using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) to generate the documentation of a number of projects of mine. I have written a simple build script that clones down all their git repos, finds the docs directory and executes:

```
sphinx-build -b html -D html_theme=treffynnon -D html_theme_path=/home/user/_themes /home/user/sphinx/src /home/user/output/docs
```

Unfortunately, whilst the `html_theme` gets set correctly the `html_theme_path` does not. This of course causes Sphinx to spit out an error when it is unable to find the theme.

How should I be formatting this command? Is it even possible to specify `html_theme_path` in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it is a known bug: https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/925/allow-html_theme_path-to-be-provided-to

To work around the problem I just used sed to do the substitution in the config file for me:

```
sed -i "s|#*html_theme = '.*'|html_theme = 'simonholywell'|g" conf.py                
sed -i "s|#*html_theme_path = .*$|html_theme_path = ['$BASE_DIR/sphinx/_themes']|g" conf.py
```

As my Sphinx projects are all in git I can then just do a:

```
git checkout -- conf.py
```

to remove the sed introduced changes after completing the build process.